# React socket.io-client not re-rendering component after response from server to a particular room (Python backend)

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have a server backend written in Python with Flask-SocketIO. I'm utilizing it's room feature to make private conversations. Upon a join room event the server fires the following function to let the frontend know where to send messages to specific user:

```
socketio.emit('room name response', {'roomName': room_name, 'recipient': recipient}, to=sid)
```

where `sid` is the private room created only for the user when connecting to a socket. Then I want to keep this information in React state in a map, like this:

```js
function ChatWindow({ username, token }) {
  const [responses, setResponses] = useState([]);
  const [roomsMap, setRoomsMap] = useState(new Map());
  const [currentRoom, setCurrentRoom] = useState("");
  const [messageValue, setMessageValue] = useState("");
  var socket = null;

  useEffect(() => {
    socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("global response", (data) => {
      setResponses((responses) => [...responses, data]);
    });

    socket.on("room name response", (data) => {
      console.log(`joined ${data.roomName} with ${data.recipient}`);
      setCurrentRoom((currentRoom) => data.roomName);
      setRoomsMap((roomsMap) => roomsMap.set(data.recipient, data.roomName));
    });

    return () => socket.close();
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = () => {
    if (messageValue.length < 1) {
      return;
    }

    socket.emit("global message", {
      user_name: username,
      message: messageValue,
      timestamp: Date.now(),
    });
    setMessageValue("");
  };

  const joinRoom = (recipient) => {
    socket.emit("join", {
      token: token,
      username: username,
      recipient: recipient,
    });

    // setCurrentRoom(() => roomsMap.get(recipient));
  };

  const leaveRoom = (recipient) => {
    socket.emit("leave", {
      token: token,
      username: username,
      recipient: recipient,
    });
    
    const newRooms = roomsMap;
    newRooms.delete(recipient);
    console.log(`left room with ${recipient}`);
    newRooms.forEach((val, key) => console.log(`${val}:${key}`));
    setRoomsMap(newRooms);
  };

  const checkUser = (userToCheck) => {
    if (userToCheck === username) {
      return styles.chatFromUser;
    } else {
      return styles.chatToUser;
    }
  };

  return (...);
}

export default ChatWindow;
```

Sadly, React doesnt react to the socket emitting message, even though it can be seen in network tab in developer tools. The `global response` works fine.
When I alter the backend function to:

```
socketio.emit('room name response', {'roomName': room_name, 'recipient': recipient})
```

React suddenly works as expected. I'm trying to understand why it happens, especially when the browser seems to see the incoming messages as stated above, so it's most likely my bad coding or some React/Javascript thing.

Thank You for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that socket sometimes was created multiple times, therefore, the socket that useEffect was currently listening wasn't necessarily the one in the room. So I made one, global socket to fix this and whole thing now works.